# Parse file name with SAS

Tags: sas

I have a directory in which every week there is a new file created. names are like below:

```
file_w1.csv
file_w2.csv
file_w3.csv
```

What I need to do is pick up the latest file (based on modified date), then parse the 2 characters just before the file extension. 
So in this case, I want 'w3' because I want to use this to know which week I am reporting for.

How can I do this in SAS?

Comment: read in the list of files, find the latest one, import it. Exactly how depends on your OS which you did not specify. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/how-to-read-latest-flat-file-based-on-date/m-p/335491/highlight/true#M75937

Comment: Please remember to show what you tried [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operating system independent technique would use SAS External File functions such as `dopen`, `fopen` and `finfo` to obtain information about a folder and it's items.

Consider this sample code that does a 'full dump' of available information whilst parsing `C:\Temp` on a Windows machine:

```
data _null_;
  length dfileref fileref $8 folder $200;

  rc = filename (dfileref, 'C:\Temp');

  did = dopen(dfileref);
  if did then do;
    do index = 1 to doptnum(did);
      featurename = doptname(did,index);  
      featurevalue = dinfo(did,featurename);
      put index= featurename= featurevalue=;
      if featurename = 'Directory' then folder = featurevalue;
    end; 

    do dindex = 1 to dnum(did);
      entryname = dread(did,dindex);
      put dindex= entryname=;

      rc = filename(fileref, cats(folder, '/', entryname));

      fid = fopen (fileref); * if entry is another folder fid will be 0;
      if fid then do;
        do findex = 1 to foptnum(fid);
          featurename = foptname(fid, findex);
          featurevalue = finfo(fid, featurename);
          put +2 findex= featurename= featurevalue=;
        end;
        fid = fclose(fid);
      end;

      rc = filename(fileref);
    end;

    did = dclose(did);
  end;

  rc = filename (dfileref);
run;
```

After examining the log you can pare down the code needed to gather specific desired information into a data set.  You can then use SQL queries to further act upon the data:

```
data csv_files(keep=fullname lastmod where=(fullname like '%.csv'));
  length dfileref fileref $8 folder $200;

  folder = 'C:\Temp';
  rc = filename (dfileref, folder);

  did = dopen(dfileref);
  if did then do;
    do dindex = 1 to dnum(did);
      entryname = dread(did,dindex);
      rc = filename(fileref, cats(folder, '/', entryname));

      fid = fopen (fileref);
      if fid then do;
        fullname = finfo(fid,'Filename');
        lastmod = input(finfo(fid,'Last Modified'), datetime18.); format lastmod datetime18.;
        output;
        fid = fclose(fid);
      end;
      rc = filename(fileref);
    end;
    did = dclose(did);
  end;
  rc = filename (dfileref);
run;

proc sql;
  create table csv_newest as 
  select *, scan(scan(fullname,-1,'_'),1,'.') as tag
  from csv_files
  where prxmatch ('/_.+\.csv$/', fullname)
  having lastmod = max(lastmod)
  ;
```